# Multiple line plot in a loop

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have data with different countries, different years and different values for several variables on each country-year. I am trying to plot several multiple line plots (the lines are these variables/year) for each country.

For some unknown reason, the plots I get in return are empty, when running the following command:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,5))
mysplits<-split(A,A$country)
for (ii in 1:length(mysplits)) {
  adf<-mysplits[[ii]]
  snames<- names(mysplits)[ii]
  p<-plot(1, 
       main=paste(snames),
       type = "n", xlim=c(1993,2015),
       ylab = "value", xlab="years", ylim=c(-50,50))
  lines(adf$year, adf$tone, col = "steelblue", lty=5)
  lines(adf$year, adf$articles, col = "pink", lty=2) 
  lines(adf$year, adf$num, col = "red", lty=3) 
  lines(adf$year, adf$gold, col = "green", lty=6)
  legend("bottomright", legend = c("EPE Public","Tone","Coverage","No of Events",
  "Conflictual"), col = c("black","steelblue","pink","red","green"),
     lty = c(1,5,2,3,6),
     cex = 1.5, seg.len=4)
     }
```

Here is the output of `dput(head(A))`:

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("AU", "BE", "BU", "DA", "EN", "EZ", "FI", 
"FR", "GM", "HR", "HU", "IT", "LG", "LH", "LO", "LU", "MT", "NL", 
"PL", "RO", "SI", "SP", "SW"), class = "factor"), year = 1994:1999, 
gold = c(-0.571428571, -2.4, 1.26, -0.2, -0.966666667, 0.316666667
), tone = c(324L, 239L, 251L, 72L, 61L, 159L), articles = c(3.571428571, 
4.5, 8.2, 4.6, 9.333333333, 6.166666667), num = c(7L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), yepe = 1995:2000, couepe = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AU", "BE", "BU", "DA", "EN", 
"EZ", "FI", "FR", "GM", "HR", "HU", "IT", "LG", "LH", "LO", 
"LU", "MT", "NL", "PL", "RO", "SI", "SP", "SW"), class = "factor"), 
epepub = c(2.01, 1.87, 0.55, 0.63, 0.52, 0.82), epepriv = c(NA, 
NA, 2.63, 2.71, 2.59, 2.12), epeind = c(0.65, 0.66, 0.72, 
0.63, 0.57, 0.53)), .Names = c("X", "country", "year", "gold", 
"tone", "articles", "num", "yepe", "couepe", "epepub", "epepriv", 
"epeind"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Here is an image of my data:

[image: Header data]

Comment: Do you have some data we can test with?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The easiest way to give some data is to use `dput(head(a))` and edit it into your opening post. Before doing this, make sure that you can replicate your problem with `head(a)`. Also, what do you mean with empty plots? Do the axes still show up or is everything white?

Comment: You can find an image of my data below. The plots show. I have a plot for each country, so the loop works. I have names for the axes and everything. It is just the added lines (also the initial line in the plot command) that don't show. It is like there was no data plotted.

Comment: hi Neena, please use `dput(A)` and add your data frame in your original question above. If data frame is too big send top 10-20 rows or sample 10-20 rows using dput..Image of data wont help to replicate a problem.

Comment: Try the same script but with `par(mfrow=c(1,1))`. If this does work and gives a plot, then the problem is that you are trying to get too many plots on a single display. With `par(mfrow=c(5,5))` each plot does not have enough room to be displayed. At least that is what seems to happen when I try to run the script.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you! Do you happen to know a way in which I could plot in a loop for all the countries in order not to do it manually for each of them? Maybe have them split between 2,3 displays?

Comment: send the plots to a graphics device: `pdf('plots.pdf'); par(mfrow=c(5,5)); for (...); dev.off()`

Comment: I converted your answer to an edit. Please don't use answers to add information to your question. Instead, [edit] the question. Also, I fixed your image. But please note that you should past the actual data in your question, not an image of the data. Images are much less useful!

Answer (score 1):

I highly, highly, highly recommend getting away from the base plotting package when trying to do complex plotting in R.  Your problem is, at Laterow pointed out, with the `par(mfrow=c(5,5))` call.  Instead of trying to debug what is going wrong there.  Please consider using ggplot, which is a much more robust, readable and flexible library for doing r plotting.  In the words of Hadley Wickham, ~"base R plotting is for creating drawings, ggplot is for understanding data"

For example, I believe the graph you are trying to produce can be accomplished with the following.  Note, there is no for loop.  In general, in R if you are using a for loop you are doing something wrong.  Also note, its  about half the lines of code and much more readable than what you originally put together.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(A, aes(x=year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=tone, colour="Tone")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=articles, colour="Coverage")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=num, colour="No of Events")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=gold, colour="Conflictual")) + 
  facet_wrap(~country) + 
  scale_colour_manual("Legend", 
                      breaks = c("Tone", "Coverage", "No of Events", "Conflictual"),
                      values = c("steelblue", "pink", "red", "green")) +
  xlab("value") + 
  ylab("years")
```

Produces:

[image: Graph]

Note your sample data only had values for the "AU" country.  However, this will **automatically** wrap you facets no matter how many countries are in this field.  This is **much more robust** than having to statically say *I have 25 countries* which appears to be what you were doing in the original attempt.